# Rinkeby Test Network

Tags: metamask, rinkeby

Am trying to get some Test Ether by following the steps in https://faucet.rinkeby.io/.
I went to twitter have made a post with the account number I want it to credit ether to.
2. Then copied the post url into rinkeby fauset and selected 18.75 eth for 3 days.
3. BNow when I do that I see "Insufficient funds for gas * price +value" error. Can someone please suggest whats going wrongs.

Comment: Issue with Rinkeby Authentication Fauset. It has worked when I tried next day.